# What Cell Option Controls Group Indentation?

Tags: notebooks

I am working on a stylesheet for a handout I am making and I want to make my own "definition" box format. So I use the "Format"->"Edit Stylesheet" menu option and get the stylesheet inspector. I then type in the name of my new stye name "DefinitionBox" and give it the style that I want. The problem is that when I apply this style it doesn't indent withing the group (ie Section or Subsection) it is in, instead it just spans the full window. For the life of me I can't figure out what option controls this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CellMargins -> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}` controls how much space is left on each side of a cell.  `CellFrameMargins` might also be of interest, if you're drawing some sort of frame around the cell (for example, like the usage messages in the documentation.)

Comment: Ugh ... I thought those numbers where calculated ... makes more sense now. Thanks!